# Error building network from vertices in spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I have a very large (shapefile) road network to read as a linear network in spatstat. So I am trying to build a basic network from reading vertices and edges as discussed in chapter 17 of book - spatial point patterns by Baddeley et al

I attach my data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_2R6KanT3YIc1FfTExwbjFJN0U)

Using this code below I get an error `Error: length(x0) == length(x1) is not TRUE`. It is not clear to me what is x0 and x1 in order to be able to find the problem.

```
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
setwd("~/documents/rwork/traced/a")

pt <- readShapePoints("collected.shp") #read vertices from a shapefile.

edgeRecords<-read.delim("edgelist.txt") #read edge connectivity list

ed<-data.frame(from=edgeRecords$from,to=edgeRecords$to)

xx<-pt@bbox[1,]#read x bounds of owin
yy<-pt@bbox[2,]#read y bounds of owin

v<-ppp(x=pt@coords[,1], y=pt@coords[,2], xx,yy) #read list of vertices


edg<-as.matrix(ed) # read node pairs as matrix

built_network<-linnet(v,edges = edg)
```

This results in error

> ```
> Error: length(x0) == length(x1) is not TRUE
> ```

Comment: We don't have access (nor would care to) to your raw data files. Please provide a small, self contained reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The data is in the link in the question. I have made access public via google drive. Is it not accessible? Running this code on that data should make it reproducible.

Comment: I have noticed that GIS files start indexing from 0, while R starts from 1. When I changed GIS to 1, it kind of works with no error, but I am not sure if I am drawing a good conclusion. I am not an R expert.

Comment: Consider encapsulating everything in this post. Keep in mind that not everyone has access to resource you currently link to and once they go offline, this question will be rendered next to useless.

Comment: If everything works fine now, you should consider answering your own question and accept the answer so it doesn't appear to still be open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in one of the comments above. I noticed that GIS indexing starts from 0 while R indexing starts from 1.

So to solve this problem, I just added +1 to the edge matrix. Because if you have collected your edge matrix from a GIS software it will have references to node zero in either from_node or to_node. If your edge matrix in R is `em` then add +1 , like so: `em+1` . A sample code could be like this

```
edgelist <- read.delim("edgelist.txt")
em <- matrix(c(edgelist$from, edgelist$to), ncol=2) +1
net <- linnet(n,edges = em)
plot(net)
```

This solved the problem for me. Hope it helps someone. Or if someone has another solution, please feel free to share.